# pandas.df.replace returning a TypeError: Unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I'm trying to convert multiple values within one column to a string value with pandas:

```
ort_raw['Location'] = ort_raw['Location'].replace({['1', 1]:['remote'],
                                                   ['0',0]:['in_lab']})
```

...where ort_raw is the `df`, `'Location'` is a particular column name, and 1 as a `string` or `int` must be `'remote'` while 0 as a `string` or `int` must be `'in_lab'`. This chunk returns the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is not a pandas error but a python one. You cannot use a list as dictionary key as the object is mutable/non-hashable. Do you have lists in your column?

Comment: `replace()` expects a dictionary as input with the values and their replacements, so you construct one beforehand, but the dictionary you are trying to create is not valid because `list` is not allowed as a key in dictionaries. You could either expand the dict to `{'1':'remote', 1:'remote', '0':'in_lab', 0:'in_lab'}` or you convert the column to string beforehand and then do the replacement (`ort_raw['Location'].astype(str).replace({'1':'remote', '0':'in_lab'})`), given that converting values other than `0`, `'0'`, `1` and `'1'` to string causes no problems.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use a unique key for each possibly.

```
ort_raw['Location'] = ort_raw['Location'].replace({'1': 'remote', 1: 'remote', '0': 'in_lab', 0: 'in_lab'})
```

If you want to compress a bit:

```
d = {'remote': [1, '1'], 'in_lab': [0, '0']}
ort_raw['Location'] = ort_raw['Location'].replace({k:v for v,l in d.items() for k in l})
```

*NB. In this particular case, you could also convert to string and only use the string key.*

```
ort_raw['Location'] = ort_raw['Location'].replace({'1': 'remote', '0': 'in_lab'})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the dictionary. Keys can't be lists.

you need to have separate keys for the integers and strings.

```
to_replace = {'1': 'remote', 1: 'remote', '0': 'in_lab', 0: 'in_lab'}
ort_raw['Location'] = ort_raw['Location'].replace(to_replace)
```